# Migrating jquery slider code to js vanilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the slider on codepen [at this link](https://codepen.io/dfitzy/pen/xZqGVo) and I'm trying to migrate the jquery code to js vanilla.
I am not able to migrate `if ($group.is(":animated"))`, is there any properties that allow me to check if an element is animated?

There is another snippet that I am not able to migrate and it is as follows:

```
$group.animate({
    left: animateLeft
}, function() {
    $slides.eq(currentIndex).css({
        display: 'none'
    });

    $slides.eq(newIndex).css({
        left: 0
    });

    $group.css({
        left: 0
    });

    currentIndex = newIndex;
});
```

Comment: You could just open the JQuery library file and search for `.is` and see the vanilla code for yourself since JQuery is nothing but vanilla JS that someone else wrote.

Comment: @ScottMarcus How would that help? `jquery.js` is ten thousand lines of fairly idiosyncratically organized Javascript and ':animated' is a jQuery extension, it's not even remotely clear how this fits together in a way you could crib into your own code.

Comment: It also misses the point of OP's question I think, my interpretation is that he wants to know how to check that an element is animated *without* jQuery, you're pointing him down a path that would basically require using jQuery's animation code. (Since the check for ':animated' seems to only look at elements jQuery is animating.)

Comment: @millimoose My interpretation of the question is different than yours.

Comment: I found the source of the pseudo selector ":animated", line 9934 - 9938, from the browser look for "pseudos.animated"

Comment: The ": animated" selector I replaced it with the [animationPlayState](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationplaystate.asp) API, only the second snippet remains.